# Prevent a button to continue when there are an errors

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

How do i prevent a button to continue when there are an errors appears?

I already can check the availability of username in database, but even though the username is not exists in the database, the "Check Availability" button still recognized it as exists.

Here is the screenshots:
[image]

Image above show the username "Seranne" already exists, but in the database, Seranne is not exists.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
else if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text)
            {
                label5.Visible = false;
                label7.Visible = false;

                conn.Open();

                CheckUsername();

                if (CheckUsername() == false)
                {
                    return;
                }

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Member] ([Username], [Password], [UserType]) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @UserType)";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["Password"].Value = this.textBox2.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("UserType", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["UserType"].Value = this.comboBox1.Text;

                int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                var dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Your username and password has been recorded", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                CreateTable();

                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                   this.Hide();

                   Form1 form = new Form1();
                   form.ShowDialog();

                   this.Close();
                }

private void CheckUsername()
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb";

            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Member]", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists! Please use another username", "Warning");
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Username is not exists!", "Congratulations");
                return true;
            }
        }
```

edit: even though the username is not exists in the database, "Check Availability" button still recognized it as exists and this is the reason that i can't proceed.

How do i solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KingKing: already attached in the question above. Please refer to it again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool CheckUsername()
{
  // return false if user name exists, otherwise tru
}
button_click(..)
{
  if(CheckUsername() == false)
  { 
     MessageBox.Show(Error Msg);
     return;
  }

  //save call
}
```

You can add a return value in CheckUserName and break out if it return false

Comment: I will try later. The code is already attached in question above. Thanks!

Comment: i already tried your code, but even though the username is not exists, the messagebox still recognized it as exists. I will edit the code in question above, please refer to it