# The "Check Availability" username button still recognized as exists, while the database the username is not exists

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

How do i prevent a button to continue when there are an errors appears?

I already can check the availability of username in database, but even though the username is not exists in the database, the "Check Availability" button still recognized it as exists.

Here is the screenshots: 
[image]

Image above show the username "Seranne" already exists, but in the database, Seranne is not exists.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
else if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text)
            {
                label5.Visible = false;
                label7.Visible = false;

                conn.Open();

                CheckUsername();

                if (CheckUsername() == false)
                {
                    return;
                }

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Member] ([Username], [Password], [UserType]) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @UserType)";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["Password"].Value = this.textBox2.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("UserType", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters["UserType"].Value = this.comboBox1.Text;

                int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();

                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                var dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Your username and password has been recorded", "Congratulations", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                CreateTable();

                if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                   this.Hide();

                   Form1 form = new Form1();
                   form.ShowDialog();

                   this.Close();
                }

private bool CheckUsername()
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb";

            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Member]", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists! Please use another username", "Warning");
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Username is not exists!", "Congratulations");
                return true;
            }
        }
```

edit: even though the username is not exists in the database, "Check Availability" button still recognized it as exists and this is the reason that i can't proceed.

How do i solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426123/prevent-a-button-to-continue-when-there-are-an-errors

Comment: @Shaharyar not really, that's the so-called `rephrasing` in a new question :))

Comment: @Shaharyar: because it is the different problem that i got, so i post a new question. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the sql as below in your CheckUsername method to accept parameter

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] =? ", conn);
```

if you select `SELECT [Username] FROM [Member]` from database it will return all the rows from the member table. but here you want to take only the members with given user name. so you can add where condition to limit the rows which match the user name like above

Comment: one question @Damith: How would i have to use "WHERE [Username] =?"?
but thanks, this is works!

Comment: one `?` is for one parameter , since you are adding one parameter it will take this as the added parameter

Comment: okay.. i got it. Thanks for your explanation and also the solution